# Using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate a point

Tags: objective-c

If I want to rotate one CGPoint about another, I'm currently doing this (which works fine):

```
    CGFloat rx = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (positionToRotate.x-rotationPoint.x) - sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (positionToRotate.y-rotationPoint.y) + rotationPoint.x;
    CGFloat ry = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (positionToRotate.x-rotationPoint.x) + cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-angle)) * (positionToRotate.y-rotationPoint.y) + rotationPoint.y;
```

It strikes me that I should be able to do this with a CGAffineTransform, but I'm a bit stuck as to how it would work:

```
CGAffineTransform affine CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);
CGPointApplyAffineTransform(positionToRotate, affine);
```

That does nothing as I'm (hopefully) missing something obvious :)
So how do you rotate a CGPoint about another without doing the matrix math myself?
Cheers,
Ian

Comment: BTW, there's an M_PI_4 constant too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGPointApplyAffineTransform` returns the transformed point.  It doesn't mutate the `CGPoint` you pass in.

```
CGPoint transformedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(positionToRotate, affine);
```

Comment: Ha! Great thanks, the 3D APIs I use usually do it like that so that's where I went wrong. Ta!